# Rounding the xtick values in a pandas plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot, xticks

Is there an easy way to round the xtick values in a pandas plot?  I plot the quantiles and this is what I get:

```
pd.Series(argmax_indexes).quantile(np.arange(0,1.05, 0.05))
0.00    500.0
0.05    560.8
0.10    582.8
0.15    589.0
0.20    593.0
0.25    595.0
0.30    596.0
0.35    597.0
0.40    598.0
0.45    598.0
0.50    599.0
0.55    599.0
0.60    599.0
0.65    600.7
0.70    602.0
0.75    603.0
0.80    606.0
0.85    608.0
0.90    616.0
0.95    634.1
1.00    699.0

pd.Series(argmax_indexes).quantile(np.arange(0,1.05, 0.05)).plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image]

Comment: What is `argmax_indexes`? Please post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: It is not important. Just use the quantiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has something to do how float64 is calculated but you can solve your problem by adjusting and writing something like this , with some sample data:

```
s = pd.Series([1,10,20,30,50]).quantile(np.arange(0,1.05, 0.05))
s.index = s.index.map(lambda l : np.around(l,2))
s.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do in one liner, this should work good:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
df['tip'].quantile(np.arange(0,1.05,0.05)).reset_index().round(2).plot(kind='bar',x='index',y='tip')
```

## output

[image]